# Алгоритм для новогоднего конкурса

Tags: javascript, filter

Алгоритм выносит вердикт по трем критериям:

- Качество языка, речи
- Количество приведенных примеров кода, чем больше, тем лучше
- Количество спамовых слов (маты, реклама, выпрашивание/задание)

http://nikitalapkov.ru/antispam/

Оцените пожалуйста, посоветуйте как улучшить

Comment: По ссылке кода нет, вопрос больше не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

[На спам не отвечаю](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulitS.png).

Если серьезно, то необходимо:

- Нормально именовать переменные или писать комментарии. Попробуй пойми зачем нужна переменная "а" или "х".
- Вынести объявление переменной "а" за пределы функции "words". Зачем повторно инициализировать при каждом вызове?
- Изменить алгоритм поиска нежелательных слов в сообщении. Нужно игнорировать регистр символом и вообще для этой задачи лучше [использовать](http://habrahabr.ru/post/101232/) регулярные выражения.
- Добавить список рекомендуемых выражений, которые повышают репутацию сообщения. К примеру: pastebin, исходник, jsfiddle...
- Учитывать репутацию вопроса, если он загружен с hashcode.
- Выполнять поиск похожих вопросов на hashcode и при нахождении понижать репутацию сообщения.
- Вопрос не обязательно должен содержать примеры кода. К примеру может обсуждаться концепция ООП, зачем ТСу примеры кода в его вопросе? Вы рассчитывать показатель "Количество примеров кода" исходя из меток вопроса: если присутствует метка определенного языка программирования или технологии, то, возможно в вопросе необходимы примеры кода.
- Учитывать репутацию пользователя-автора вопроса, если последний загружен с hashcode.

Comment: Я ждал, что кто-нить протестит мой вопрос :) Спасибо, ваш голос будет учтен!

Comment: Вообще, можно судить из описания конкурса, что админы предполагали совсем иной уровень спам-фильтра: задействование нейронный сетей, мощного синтаксического анализоватора, генетических алгоритмов... Это задача как раз для команды опытных разработчиков, но энтузиастов, как видим, немного...

Comment: @uzumaxy, IMHO идея изначально нереализуема, т.к. по поводу разделения на хороший-плохой сколько людей, столько и мнений.

Поэтому ее здесь даже обсуждать толком не стали.

Comment: @uzumaxy, прочитайте комментарии к заданию-вы правы лишь частично

Comment: @Arc, прочитал комменты. Не могу понять в чем неправ, подскажите.

Comment: @avp, я тоже думал об этом - более менее достоверно можно определить только рекламный спам (посетите наш сайт), предложения о работе и очень наглую просьбу выполнить работу за автора, но это как-то слишком мелочно по сравнению с поставленной новогодней задачей :)

Comment: @uzumaxy, решение с нейронными сетями было отвергнуто и была высказана идея сделать что попроще.

Comment: @Arc, там указано лишь на сложность реализации, сама идея использования нейронных сетей вовсе не отвергается. Не перекручивайте текст. 

Я писал ранее:

> можно судить из описания конкурса, что админы предполагали совсем иной уровень спам-фильтра


То есть задействовать сложные технологии *придется* исходя из предполагаемой сложности реализуемого алгоритма. В 100 строк JS тут не обойтись, это детское решение.